# How to accept a list of files on the command line and use xargs to create a dated copy of all of them (basename_date.extension)?

Tags: bash, shell-script, date, xargs, echo

I've been spending quite a lot of time working this problem from [here](https://ryanstutorials.net/bash-scripting-tutorial/bash-variables.php) out and I've managed to get the correct output without leaning on xargs calling `bash` (which the tutorial hasn't covered). It took a while to get the quoting right with the child `bash` call within `xargs` and for some reason I had to save the `replace-str` in a variable as well as recalculate the `date` and save it in a new variable because:

EDIT: I understand that `rename` can be used to solve this as well, but that was not yet covered in the tutorial I linked and not the point of this exercise (which, as stated before, is to use xargs)

- apparently param expansion doesn't apply to the `replace-str` = {} so I can't do "{}%%.*" and get the file extension
- apparently even a double quoted variable, `today`, will be null if used within the child bash process run within an `xargs` command.

```
    # %<conversions> come from 'man 3 strftime'                                                                                                                  
    today=$( date "+%Y-%m-%d" )

    # make prefix date copy                                                                                                                                      
    #ls "$@" | xargs -I ^ cp ^ "${today}_^"                                                                                                                        

    #make suffix date copy                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    echo "$@" | sed "s; ;\n;g" | xargs -I {} \
                          bash -cs 'var="{}"; td=$( date "+%Y-%m-%d" ); \
                                    echo "${var%%.*}_${td}.${var##*.}"'
    #prints basename_.bash i.e. without date
    echo "$@" | sed "s; ;\n;g" | xargs -I {} \
                          bash -cs 'var="{}"; \
                                    echo "${var%%.*}_${today}.${var##*.}"'
```

will output

```
    s1_2021-03-11.bash s2_2021-03-11.bash
```

on input

```
    ./myscript s1.bash s2.bash
```

EDIT: To reiterate the input will look like

```
    ./myscript file1.ext file2.ext file3.ext ... fileN.ext
```

and after running `ls` there should exist files that look like

```
    file1_yyyy-mm-dd.ext ... fileN_yyyy-mm-dd.ext
```

If possible I would rather find a solution that DOES NOT use `bash -c` because the tutorial on the website has not yet covered that and so I doubt it was intended to be a solution to the problem. I'd also like to understand my confusion about param expansion no working with xargs and the need for another date variable.

Comment: I suggest you look up the `rename` command. Unfortunately, there are at least two quite different versions of it out there, but they should both allow you to rename large numbers of files with ease rather than getting into complicated shell scripting. For example, my version uses regular expressions. This here `rename "s/$/.$today/" *` appends the date to all filenames.

Comment: The other type of `rename` takes a static string and renames it. It is much less flexible. `rename . _$today. *` replaces the dot in all filenames with `_$today.`. This doesn't work as intended when a filename contains more than one dot; you may want to do it by extension then: `rename .bash _$today.bash *`.

Comment: @berndbausch Thanks for the comment, I actually had developed up a version that used rename but the tutorial hadn't covered that yet and specifically mentioned xargs in the problem statement (trying to get me used to using it I guess) so I have decided to forego it's use. I'll add a comment in the question to disallow rename. Regardless I appreciate it!

Comment: It will be good if you also wrote the input and the expected output.

Comment: @guest_7 I thought I did wrote the expected input and output but in hindsight it might not have been clear enough I will edit the question with it clearer.

Comment: Using unquoted `$@` is wrong. For it to work properly it must always be inside double quotes, `"$@"`

Comment: @roaima thanks for the suggestion, I made sure to test it with `$@` quoted. I'm not exactly sure why using it unquoted is "wrong," as the output of the program is identical. But if you would care to link to an elaboration or elaborate yourself I'd appreciate it!

Comment: The tutorial has beautifully written text, but many of the script examples will teach you poor habits. None of the variables in any script I saw are double-quoted, so they will all break when you encounter a filename with a space in it. Later, the use of `cat /dev/stdin` is a pointless expression - just omit it entirely and the next command in the pipe will read from _stdin_ itself. If you use `$@` unquoted you'll end up with an unquoted list of values from the command line. Double-quote it (`"$@"`) and all the values will become safely double-quoted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we do not have access to GNU version of xargs/sed , then we need to take the responsibility to quote filenames safe for xargs.

Usage:

```
 ./myscript   your list of files goes here
```

```
#!/bin/bash

# user defined function: qXargs
# backslashes all chars special to xargs:
# SPC/TAB/NL/double quotes, single quotes, and backslash.

qXargs() {
  printf '%s\n' "$1" |
  sed \
    -e "s:[\\'${IFS%?}\"]:\\\\&:g" \
    -e '$!s:$:\\:'  \
  ;
}

# loop over command-line arguments
# quote them to make xargs safe and
# break apart arg into head portion and
#'extension and slip in today's date

today=$(date +'%Y-%d-%m')

for arg
do
   src=$(qXargs "$arg")
  head=$(qXargs "${arg%.*}")
  tail=$(qXargs "${arg##*.}")
  printf '%s\n%s_%s.%s\n'  \
    "$src" \
    "$head" "$today" "$tail" ;
done | xargs -n 2 -t mv -f --
```

---

Assuming GNU versions of utilities.

```
#!/bin/bash
### this is the ./myscript file
d=$(date +'%Y-%d-%m')
printf '%s\0' "$@" |
sed -Ez "p;s/(.*)(\..*)/\1$d\2/" |
xargs -r0 -n2 -t mv -f --
```

---

Notes:

- Your confusion regarding not being able to get the extension from the xargs replacement string {} is bcoz {} is just a placeholder to remind xargs to replace it with the argument. So the shell while parsing the xargs command cannot see it.

Comment: Really appreciate the answer, I made edits to clarify the comment you made before about the expected input and output. Regarding parsing `ls` I don't think I do, I parse `echo`, though I see you might have noticed I parse `ls` in a commented out section. That's super interesting about `printf` though! I'll make sure to see if I can work something out with it.

Comment: the output on running with your solution was 
```tr: Illegal byte sequence
tr: Illegal byte sequence
sed: illegal option -- z```
but honestly this is so much more complicated than I think it needs to be. This challenge question is from an intro to scripting tutorial and with all due respect your solution seems to be overkill.

Comment: Actually the solution is the last 3 lines. The rest of the paraphernalia is just to create random file names. Now your sed doesn't take -z means you are not using GNU version of it.

Comment: Well, I can't complain. The solution works and it doesn't require a call to `bash`. I'll wait a little to see if anyone else adds a non-GNU version that's a little more beginner, but otherwise I'll accept your answer. Thanks for the response! It sent me down some interesting rabbit holes.